# editing a JSON file with sed

Tags: regex, json, bash, sed

I need to edit a JSON file, using `sed`, to add some data in to the file. The JSON is as follows:

```
{
  'name':
  // more attributes that are already filled in 
}
```

I have written this `sed` command to try and do it:

```
sed "s/(\'name\':)/\1\"hello\"\,/g" /path/to/file.json
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
sed: \1 not defined in the RE
```

The expected results are:

```
{
  'name': "hello",
  // more attributes here, left untouched
}
```

I know this is a bad way of doing it, but I don't think I am able to use tools such as [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) because the file will be edited on a server and I cannot install `jq` on the server. If anyone has a better solution i'd be very interested to hear it. Thank you!

Comment: For cascading languages (like JSON) one better never ever uses regular expressions, but uses context-free grammars or even better: specific language tools. Especially if you want your tool to be reliable, it is really bad practice: eventually it will always go wrong one way or another.

Comment: As you stated, it's a bad practice. `jq` can be downloaded as-is and executed without dependencies

Comment: do you need to escape the colon? Might be worth a shot.

Comment: agree with above about not using sed, but not all `sed`s work the same way. You might need to use `'s/\(\'name\':\)/\1....'`. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use python, it's so much easier and on most POSIX systems:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
jsonObject = json.load(filename)
jsonObject['name'] = "hello"
json.dump(filename, jsonObject)
```

And run it:

```
python parse_json.py
```

EDIT: To use this in a bash setting, use a here document:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ...

# set the name variable to something
name=VALUE

# ...

# and use it in a here document
parse_json_script=$(mktemp parse_json.XXXX.py)
cat > $parse_json_script << SCRIPT
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
jsonObject = json.load(filename)
# You can use bash variables in here documents.
# the line below uses the bash variable `name` and inserts it into the python script
jsonObject['name'] = "$name"
print(jsonObject['name'])
json.dump(filename, jsonObject)
SCRIPT
python $parse_json_script && rm $parse_json_script
```

The foregoing script uses a here document to create a python script on the fly and run it to alter the JSON, then removes the parse json script afterwards.

Personally, though, I prefer to use the `sh` module of python and just write the script in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals 
import sh

# now you can call any command as if it were a python function
sh.ls("-lah") # `ls -lah`, but maybe you use python's `os` module instead
sh.rsync("-avHAX","foo","bar")
```

Between python's `sh` (command execution), `os` (file manipulation), `shutil` (recursive file manipulation) and `re` (regex) modules, I find bash's functionality may be generally completely replaced.

Comment: Been exploring this option, it seems to work well, however, I need to run this inside a larger Bash script, and the `"hello"` value will actually be a Bash variable. How would I combine Bash and Python?

Comment: I added what you requested to the answer.

Comment: thanks for adding that, it works great :) I had to edit your Python a little to get it to work on my system though:
    `import json`
    `with open('package.json', 'r+') as f:`
        `data = json.load(f)`
        `data["name"] = "$newstring"`
        `f.seek(0)`
        `json.dump(data, f, indent=4)`

Answer (score 7):

As you stated, `sed` is not the right tool here, instead, use a proper JSON parser :

#### INPUT json

```
$ cat json
{
  "name": "foobar"
}
```

#### using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
$ jq '.name |= "qux"' json | tee json
```

(the latest with [tee](/questions/tagged/tee) work with small files)

#### or using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -i -MJSON -0ne '
    my $DS = decode_json $_;
    $DS->{name} = "qux";
    print encode_json $DS
' json
```

remove the `-i` switch if you want to test the command without editing the file *in place*

#### OUTPUT json

```
$ cat json
{
  "name": "qux"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sputnick, will try to implement this with my system, it looks much better than using `sed`, I just wasn't sure of the alternatives.

Comment: The command with jq is not working

Answer (score 5):

You have the backslashes in the wrong places. `'` does not need to be escaped, but the parentheses do. This works:

```
sed "s/\('name':\)/\1\"hello\"\,/g" /path/to/file.json
```

Note: I'm assuming that file.json is not a json file but a specially crafted template, otherwise this substitution wouldn't make any sense (the result would not be JSON). Working on JSON files with sed is quite certainly a bad idea, so if you're trying to modify JSON rather than generating it, take a look at `jq` or so instead.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse JSON !

Comment: If file.json is a JSON file, the resulting file would not be JSON. I think he's working on a use-case specific template that is crafted so as to make it okay.

Comment: Thanks Wintermute, this is great. Got a bit confused with the backslashes! @sputnick, I understand the worries and I am a little uneasy about it too but it's not an important file and if something goes wrong, it's not a massive issue. I looked at jq but it's not practical to use it in this situation.

Comment: Answers are not just for you, the questions/answers have own life, and people searching with search engines will pick the bad practices if bad practices are accepted.

Comment: I added something to make it clear. Again, though, the input file cannot be valid JSON if the output file is to be, so "use JSON tools" is not a helpful answer to this question.

Comment: Cudos for actually answering the question asked rather pretending to know better. sed works on pretty much any linux setup and the others require installing something.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/'name':/& \"hello\",/" File
```

Almost similar to Wintermutes's answer, but here we are avoiding the `(grouping)` and therefore instead of `\1` we use `& (pattern matched)`. Also, `global substitution (g)` is not required if only one occurence of `'name':` in each line. I'm not sure if sed is the right tool for the job though. I do not know JSON yet. :-)